# Chebyshev differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, chebyshev-polynomials

Consider the Chebyshev polynomial of the first kind
$$ (1-x^2)y'' - xy' + n^2y = 0 , n \in \mathbb{N}. $$
Use the substitution $ x=\cos\theta $ and show that the transformed ODE has solutions $y_1 = \cos (n\theta)$ and $y_2 = \sin (n\theta)$.

I have tried substituting in $\cos \theta $ for $x$ and then substituting in the given solutions for $y$, but I have been unable to show it is equal to zero.

The substitution yields
$$ (1-\cos^2 \theta )y'' - \cos (\theta)y' + n^2y$$
and upon substituting in the respective derivatives of $y_1$, I get the left had side to be
$$ (1- \cos^2 \theta )(-n^2 \cos (n \theta )) - \cos (\theta )(-n \sin (n\theta )) + n^2\cos (n\theta)$$

which I am struggling to show equals zero.

Comment: You should include the new differential equation you obtain in terms of $\theta$ after the initial substitution.

Comment: @podiki  I've updated the question now to include some of my current workings out. Hope that helps!

Comment: This is not quite correct, because in the original equation $y' = \frac{dy}{dx}$ and you need to rewrite the equation in terms of $\frac{dy}{d\theta}$. For this you can use the chain rule, $\frac{d}{d\theta} = \frac{dx}{d\theta}\frac{d}{dx}$

Comment: It is better to change the letter if the function changes. you want $u(\theta)=y(\cos\theta)$ and you have to use the chain rule to compute the first two derivatives of $u$. Then use $u$ and its derivative to eliminate $y$ in all forms.